# c++ localtime to mysql datetime

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime

I have a c++ time double that records seconds since 1 Jan 1970.

I want to convert this double and store it in a MySQL database, so here is my code to convert it firstly to a datetime format: *NOTE: ss.time is the double..

```
/* do the time conversion */
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
rawtime = (time_t)ss.time;
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
```

This code converts it to the following format: Thu Jul 24 05:45:07 1947

I then attempt to write it to the MySQL database as follows:

```
string theQuery = "UPDATE readings SET chng = 1, time = CAST('";
theQuery += boost::lexical_cast<string>(asctime(timeinfo));
theQuery += "' AS DATETIME) WHERE id = 1";
```

It does not work, but updates the time DATETIME variable in the table with NULL.

Can someone tell me how to do a correct conversion and update the SQL table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your c++ double is just a standard Unix timestamp, which MySQL can convert using its [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function:

```
UDPATE ... SET ... time=FROM_UNIXTIME(rawtime)
```

Comment: For some reasons, when I try and update using FROM_UNIXTIME() and put 3586767203 into the brackets, which was the time of the reading, it enters null into the fields?

Comment: mysql only supports 32bit unix time_t, which maxes out in early 2038. Your timesetamp is in Aug 2083, far beyond the limit.